# Send a copy of All Packets to another ip address

Tags: networking, router, dsl

I have to send a copy of all network traffics of one company to another. Both are not directly connected but they could connect through Internet(they have valid ip address). The purpose is some kind of analyzing the captured data in short period of times not all day long. Both companies are connected to the internet via 2 DSL Router zyxel P-660HW Series with [features describe here](http://www.zyxel.com/products_services/p_660hw_series.shtml?t=p).

Is there any solution without buying a new featured router or any device or server to both sides?

Is there any way we could modify router or router OS to do send a copy of packets to other destination?

*Note: If I could send Source traffic to the Destination, 90% of my problem will be solved.

*Note: Source router -physically- is hardly reachable and it is in another City.

Comment: There are a lot of security concern of doing this, do you have a VPN between the 2 companies? What network traffic needs to be logged? Is it visible from the router (I mean do the source router sees all the traffic it is supposed to send to the destination router)?

Comment: Security is not a priority at this time and they don't have VPN connection and i want to capture all network traffic , Yes , source router do also switching in its network, i edited the question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a packet sniffer, you have to buy a router that has this feature. It's worth the time you have to spend configuring this scenario and the cheap routers can't handle the large amount of data and heavy routing, as they don't have enough CPU power and memory to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this simply by adding a route to your source router and add forwarder to your destination Router and add routing feature to your destination Pc , if it is Linux , you don't need any additional software , if it is windows I think you better install Win Server and add Route feature to it .